# Sortable Table + Form + Update Info

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

So I am making an app where one is able to enter client info (Name, address, email, phone number, etc). After the form data is submitted into the sql table, I want to be taken back to a page with a table, sortable by name or date added, of all the clients, how can I do this?

Comment: Use Gridview 1.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/gridview-examples-for-Asp-Net-2-0/ 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Comment: Thanks, would have chosen this as the answer but can't since it's a comment, good stuff though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webforms use the event handler of submit button. In the event handler after the data is saved to table, use `Response.Redirect()` to redirect the request to new page which has a gridview populated with data from the table.

Comment: Thanks, an actual response that has what i need to use and not some sass about my question